# Oracle inequality comparison - invalid number

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to create an alert in my system with the below code. I have tried changing it up a bit but am receiving errors or no data returned.

In my select statement I have figured the difference in days from the date data against sysdate. In my where clause I am trying to restrict the data coming through by using a less than or equal to operator.

```
SELECT A.COL_NAME AS "END OF SERVICE", B.DUSER AS "DATE",(TRUNC(B.DUSER) - TRUNC(SYSDATE))AS "DAYS LEFT"
FROM UD_COLS A LEFT OUTER JOIN UD_DATA B
ON A.ID = B.UD_COLS_ID
WHERE A.ID = 52 AND
('DAYS LEFT' <= 30)
```

This results in error: ORA-01722: invalid number
I have tried changing the select to add TO_NUMBER(TRUNC(B.DUSER) - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) and still receive the same error.

I have also tried changing to ('DAYS LEFT' <= '30') which I receive no error, but the data is not returned as expected.

Without the ('DAYS LEFT' <= 30) in there I see a value of 1 in the "DAYS LEFT" column. Is this not a numerical value?

If I use a >= operator, the data populates regardless of the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't define an expression in the SELECT list and then refer to it in the WHERE clause. Also, single quotes define text literals not identifiers (use double quotes for those), and the above code is SQL not PL/SQL.

Comment: You seem very confused about data types. Why would you ever try 'DAYS LEFT' <= '30'? That compares two constant text strings to each other - since 3 comes before D in the ASCII ordering of characters, the condition is always false. In any case it would have nothing to do with the data. What you do want is the arithmetic expression you aliased as `"DAYS LEFT"` (using, correctly, double-quotes in `select`). Why are you using single quotes in `where` - because the double quoted version throws an error? The error has an unrelated cause, as William Robertson explained above.

Comment: Thank you guys. This is very helpful. I'm just starting my journey with relational databases, SQL, DML, and everything else involved. A lot of the stuff I was reading was foreign, so I appreciate you taking your time and dumbing it down for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

William Robertson explained in a Comment to your question what's wrong with your code (two things, one that can be corrected - change single quotes to double quotes - and another that can't be fixed - you can't reference in the `where` clause an alias defined in the `select` clause of the same query).

The simplest fix is to change the `where` clause to

```
where b.duser < trunc(sysdate) + 31
```

This is equivalent to your condition using `trunc(b.duser)`, but it is written in such a way that no function calls are applied to `b.duser` - resulting in faster execution, and in MUCH faster execution if you have an index on that column.